# In SQL, 'distinct' reduces the number of result rows from one to zero

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL statement of the following structure:

```
select distinct ...
from table1,
(select from table2, table3, table4 where ...)
where ...
order by ...
```

With certain values in the where clauses, the statement returns zero rows in the result set. When I remove the 'distinct' keyword, it returns a single row. I would expect to see a single result row in both cases. Is there some property of the 'distinct' keyword that I am not aware of and that causes this behavior?

The database is Oracle 11g.

Comment: Do you have the DDL and DMLs for this select?

Comment: Can you not build an example we can actually try ourselves?

Comment: Adding DISTINCT removes the duplicates and returns only unique rows: so this does not seem possible that using distinct would give you zero result set and removing it gives one.

Comment: Thank you for fast responses! I will need to wait a couple of hours to clear if I can post the statement in a forum. As for DDL and DML, this is probably a very rare situation, so I doubt that I can construct an artificial example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that one of the sub-selects resulted in a data set that contained, among others, a row where every column was NULL. It seems that this row influenced the evaluation of the DISTINCT in a non-obvious way (at least to me). Maybe this is due to some under-the-hood SQL optimizations. After I removed the cause of this NULL-filled row, the problem is gone and the statement evaluates to one row in the result as it should.

Comment: Suggest you accept your own answer. And it does look like a bug so a db version maybe useful if anyone else hits the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is not the expected behaviour of DISTINCT.  This is:

```
SQL> select * from dual
  2  /

D
-
X

1 row selected.

SQL> select distinct * from dual
  2  /

D
-
X

1 row selected.

SQL>
```

So, if what you say is happening really is what is happening then it's a bug.  However, you also say it's a rare occurrence which means there is a good chance it is some peculiarity in your data and/or transient conditions in your environment, and not a bug.

You need to create a reproducible test case, for two reasons.  Partly, nobody will be able to investigate your problem without one.  But mainly because building a test case is an investigation in its own right: attempting to isolate the precise combination of data and/or ambient factors often generates the insight which leads to a solution.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Next time I will provide a better example.